# Weird node edit form behavior with feeds imported nodes

Tags: 7, nodes, feeds

got a weird situation going on. I imported a bunch of nodes from a csv file using the feeds module to a particular content type. This conent type have different type of field like address field, entity reference, and a lot of long text.

All records from the file are imported and I can see all the nodes properly. But when I go in edit mode, All the text fields are empty. Title, address, dates and links fields are ok, but all text are empty. The data is in the database as well as showing on the node, but not in the edit mode.

This is of course causing me problems as when you have to edit, you"loose" all the text. I have a multilingual site...but all those node are set to english...and it's working. The only thing I saw was the fields table didn't seem to get the language value from the node set by the feeds. But I updated it manually in the table and it's not helping anyway.

Th encoding of the csv is utf-8..and I use \n as line break....it's an export of mysql.

Any idea why it's doing this? What I am doing something wrong? Is there a special trick to apply to prevent this...it's driving me crazy..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok,I found the problem. Seems like feeds does not support languages. So in order to make it work, you need to manually update the language of the field in both the data and the revision table for the node you imported using feeds. Once both table are done, the data appears in the edit form.

Comment: well...sounds like it's working...but not 100%. Most of the imported are working properly in the edit form, but form some...it doesn't. Only the text field. Title, address, dates are good. I compared node that are working with those that are not and haven't found any major difference in the data stored in the table...also looked at the flat file lines and same thing there...nothing major. Did this ever happen to anyone? It's driving me nuts...I'm kinda stuck with this...I need to publish those nodes but if some don't work in the edit form, the client won't be able to edit them...so...